# Where can I find last "blue screen" error message after reboot in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Just saw a "blue screen" in Windows 10. I wanted to google the error message but the moment I reached the phone to take a photo - computer rebooted.

Can I find this error message somewhere in the logs?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, it's recorded in the Event Log. I quote the [bsod](/questions/tagged/bsod) tag wiki:

> If you didn't catch the BSOD display, information about the crash can be found in in System event log (viewable in the Event Viewer, `eventvwr.msc`). Error events from the `BugCheck` source contain the bugcheck code, the parameters, and the path to the dump file on the General tab. Critical events from the `Kernel-Power` source contain the code and parameters in the `EventData` section of the Details tab.
>
> For a list of all possible BSOD errors and their descriptions, see the [Bug Check Code Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh994433(v=vs.85).aspx).

Once you get the numeric bugcheck code as a hexadecimal number, you can consult that reference to find its symbolic name.

Comment: The general tab has only this information: `The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.` I can't find an error message there.

Comment: Right, the `Kernel-Power` events only show the bugcheck code on the **Details** tab. `BugCheck` events have that information on the General tab.

Comment: There is no message there either. There is BugCheck Code and some other numbers but no actual message that I saw on a "blue screen".

Comment: @Boykodev Right, you need to look up the code in the code reference. I'll make that clearer in my answer.

Comment: So no way to see an error message again? Because googling the BugCheck Code not giving me that message.

Comment: @Boykodev Please look at the linked "Bug Check Code Reference" document to find the name from the number.