# How can I view a blue screen of death for longer?

Tags: bsod, windows-11

One of my computers is experiencing blue screens of death. Unfortunately, the blue screen shows up for a fraction of a second before the computer restarts, which is making it hard for me to troubleshoot the cause.

Is there a way to stop the computer from restarting immediately so I can see what the exact error message is? Alternatively, is there a way to see from the log (below) what the cause of the BSOD is? The operating system is Windows 11.

> BugcheckCode    340
>
> BugcheckParameter1  0xffffce85db24f000
>
> BugcheckParameter2  0x0
>
> BugcheckParameter3  0x0
>
> BugcheckParameter4  0x0
>
> SleepInProgress 0
>
> PowerButtonTimestamp    0
>
> BootAppStatus   0
>
> Checkpoint  41
>
> ConnectedStandbyInProgress  false
>
> SystemSleepTransitionsToOn  12
>
> CsEntryScenarioInstanceId   46
>
> BugcheckInfoFromEFI true
>
> CheckpointStatus    0
>
> CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2 46
>
> LongPowerButtonPressDetected    false

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1097234/where-can-i-find-last-blue-screen-error-message-after-reboot-in-windows-10

Comment: @Anaksunaman that's where I got the log from, but the vendor of the computer is asking for the error message, e.g. IRQL_NOT_LESS.

Comment: the stopcode is 0x340. That is what you can give to the vendor, as it is an extremely rare stop code. See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/eql1um/extremely_bizarre_blue_screen_of_death_stop_0x340/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open regedit and navigate to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl

make new 32bit dword

> DisplayParameters

set to 1

reboot.

Now you will get the old bsod screen if it does bsod.

To keep the screen up until you press and hold the power button:

Find Advanced System Settings, then click settings button in "startup and recovery" section, then clear the tick box for "Automatically restart". Hit OK, OK.

This may help but to find the real cause you will have to debug the crash dump file using [WinDbg tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools).